# Authenticating a phone for an ASP.NET MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8.1

So I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and it already has Identity 2.0 so getting authentication to work on it wasn't too hard. The problem I've ran into is authenticating a phone.

I'm building a Windows Phone 8.1 app that is going to connect to the MVC app to get/send data. Sure that isn't that hard either, just create MVC actions that return and accept XML/JSON data. But the problem is that I need to make sure that the phone accessing the web actions is authenticated, as in, the user has logged in on the phone app. What would be the easiest way to make this work so that the web service receiving the call can tell that the phone is a logged in user?

Note: The user profiles on the phone are the same ones that are used in the main MVC app, so if you register in the MVC app using your browser, you can use the same credentials to log in using the phone app.